# Find expected value of $Y$ if $P(Y=\frac{1}{2^a})=\frac{1}{2^a}$

Tags: probability, expected-value

C​onsider the following random variable $Y$. It takes only values of the form $\frac{1}{2^a}$ for positive integer $a$ and $P(Y=\frac{1}{2^a})=\frac{1}{2^a}$ for each $a$. Find expected value of this random variable. Enter answer as a proper fraction.

My compute is:

a. Expectation is
$$E(x)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} P_{k}X_{k}\ \Rightarrow\ E(x)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^a}\frac{1}{2^a}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2a}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2}}\frac{1}{2^{a}}$$

$$a=\frac{1}{4} ;\quad r = \frac{1}{2};\quad \frac{a}{1-r}=2.$$

Apparently I made an error but I am not able to see it.

Thanks in advance

edit:  attached the image of the statement
[image]

add sugestion platform.

[image]

Comment: The wording of the problem seems incorrect. Which values does $X$ take, $k$ or $\frac{1}{2^a}$?

Comment: I add image of wording in the main, but I think that is \frac{1}{2}

Comment: $\frac 1{2^{2a}}\neq \frac 1{2^2}\times \frac 1{2^a}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use $k$ as for the index.

$$\mathbb E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^k}\cdot \frac1{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{ 2^k\cdot 2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{ 4^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac1{ 4}\right)^k$$

Therefore here $r=\frac1{ 4}$. Using the formula of the geometric series we have

$$\mathbb E(X)=\frac1{ 4}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac1{ 4}}=...$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I have been clueless, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm pleased that it helps. Feel free to accept the answer.